# Is it possible to use terraform to destroy ec2 instance without a state file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to destroy an ec2 instance without the state file?
I want to destroy the instance by its tag name.

Thanks

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Terraform is not the tool that you can use to manage some *random* resources in your AWS cloud. The concept of Terraform is completely different, it does not work without the state file.

For your task you have to use [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).